# Labling neighboring cell faces in a grid

Tags: python, pandas, grid

I have a list of nodes in a pandas data frame that look like this:

```
    row  col
    ... 
36  182  240          
35  182  241          
34  182  242          
33  182  243         
58  183  220          
32  183  244          
31  183  245          
30  183  246          
29  183  247          
    ...
```

The grid of this nodes are looking like this:

[image]

My code labels each face of the X-ed cells so that if it is connected to the adjustment X-ed cell it gets labeled as 0 and if it is not connected (open) it gets labeled as 1. The code is not working properly along some of the edges:

```
df["Front Face"] = 1
df["Back Face"]  = 1
df["Right Face"] = 1
df["Left Face"]  = 1

df = df.sort_values(by=['row','col'], ascending=True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
for ix1 in df.index:
    try:
        if df["col"][ix1] == df["col"][ix1 + 1] - 1:
            df["Right Face"][ix1] = 0
            df["Left Face"][ix1 + 1]  = 0
        if df["col"][ix1] == df["col"][ix1 - 1] + 1:
            df["Left Face"][ix1] = 0
            df["Right Face"][ix1 - 1]  = 0
    except:
        pass


df= df.sort_values(by=['col','row'], ascending=True)
df= df.reset_index(drop=True)
for ix2 in df.index:
    try:
        if df["row"][ix2] == df["row"][ix2 + 1] - 1:
            df["Back Face"][ix2] = 0
            df["Front Face"][ix2 + 1]  = 0
        if df["row"][ix2] == df["row"][ix2 - 1] + 1:
            df["Front Face"][ix2] = 0
            df["Back Face"][ix2 - 1]  = 0
    except:
        pass
```

This is part of the output with cell 182,243 and 183,244 missing one label:

```
    row  col  Front Face  Back Face  Right Face  Left Face
36  182  240          1           1          0           0
35  182  241          1           1          0           0
34  182  242          1           1          0           0
33  182  243          1           0          1           0
58  183  220          1           0          1           1
32  183  244          0           1          0           1
31  183  245          1           1          0           0
30  183  246          1           1          0           0
29  183  247          1           1          0           0
```

I circled the problematic cells in the picture here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume every row in your `df` marks an occupied position and you want to mark the adjacent cells as Front, Back, Left or Right.

If so, you can do this in a vectorized way but I have to admit: I struggled a lot with the getting the indexes and the numpy broadcast to work right.

```py
# A random 5 * 10 matrix with 10% of rows marked as "occupied"
n, m = 5, 10
count = int(n * m * 0.1)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'row': np.random.randint(n, size=count),
    'col': np.random.randint(m, size=count)
}).drop_duplicates()
```

And let's build the `result` data frame:

```py
from itertools import product

# Every row in `df` marks an occupied position
result = df.set_index(['row', 'col']).assign(Occupied = True)

# Now expand `result` into the full matrix
idx = product(range(n), range(m))
result = result.reindex(idx, fill_value=False)

# Every cell is Open initially
for col in ['Front Face', 'Back Face', 'Right Face', 'Left Face']:
    result[col] = 1

# Now start to build out a list of blocked cells
occupied = result.query('Occupied').index.to_frame().to_numpy()
valid_index = result.index

faces = {
    'Front Face': [-1, 0],
    'Back Face': [1, 0],
    'Left Face': [0, -1],
    'Right Face': [0, 1]
}

for face, offset in faces.items():
    blocked = valid_index.intersection([tuple(i) for i in occupied + offset])
    result.loc[blocked, face] = 0
```

To illustrate the result, let's build a helper function:

```py
from IPython.display import display

def illustrate(result):   
    display_df = result['Occupied'].map({True: 'x', False: ''}).reset_index()
    display_df = display_df.pivot(index='row', columns='col', values='Occupied')
    
    is_open = result[['Front Face', 'Back Face', 'Right Face', 'Left Face']].all(axis=1)
    style_df = (
        is_open.map({
            True: 'background-color: white',
            False: 'background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.2)'
        })
        .unstack()
    )
    
    display(display_df.style.apply(lambda _: style_df, axis=None))

illustrate(result)
```

Result (the cells in red have a 0 on *any* of the faces):

[image: labeled grid]

Comment: Very elegant solution.